# Negate the value going to less than 0

Tags: android

I have this code in the if else statement... I'm trying to block the textview value from going below 0, but it still goes below 0.

```
else if(iv1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane2).getConstantState())){
                    int e =Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                    int f = e-1;
                    String s3 = String.valueOf(f);
                    textView5.setText(s3);
                    int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                    if(dInt <= 0)
                                  {

                                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GameOver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                  }

                }
```

P.S. sorry for my english i`ve lessen my code but it still goes to a negative value

Comment: where did you restrict it...? And please explain clearly what do you want...

Comment: i`m restricting the textview5 to not get a value lower than 0 or a negative value

Comment: I haven't found that in your code....

Comment: i`m using this one int dInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                    if(dInt <= 0)

Comment: You haven't restricted there you just kept a toast message to check whether it is less than 0 or not...but you haven't restricted than.. Try my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if  (iv1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane1).getConstantState())) {{
                    int a=Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                    int b=a+12;
                    String s1 = String.valueOf(b);
                    textView5.setText(s1);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                } int aInt = Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                 if(aInt <= 0) 
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WrongWa",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if   (iv1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.airplane2).getConstantState())){

                     int c=Integer.parseInt(textView5.getText().toString());
                         int  d=c-2;
                      String s1 = String.valueOf(d);
                     textView5.setText(s1);
                     {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    }
            }


            });
```

i`ve tried this and it actually works the way i want ito to be @Pragnani thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Math.max does what you want.

```
int b = Math.max(a - 2, 0);
```

Comment: it goes for the toast "Wrong" but after the event of the other button where it adds a value to textView.5 it does not subtract the value of the textView5

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean.